Possible improvement in proof for showing that the maximum/minimum value of an LLP, is at an extreme point.
Have found a proof in a text book, title: Mathematical Programming for Operations Researchers and Computer Scientists
By Albert G. Holzman.
It is stated below, to prove that the maximum/minimum value of a LPP exists only at an extreme point.
But, the proof seems not convincing enough; and feel that it lacks. Seems only a different way to prove is needed.
Proof: Based on the hypothesis that the finite set of feasible solutions is convex for a given LP problem, need prove that the optimal solution (maximum or minimum) will be located at an extreme point of the convex set.
The objective function is assumed to be denoted by $f(X).$ And, let there be $q$ extreme points, denoted by $\overline{X_1}, \overline{X_2}, \cdots, \overline{X_q}, $ and the maximum feasible solution by $X_0.$
Assume that $X_0$ is not an extreme point, then it is an internal point of the convex set of feasible solutions.
Hence, $X_0$ can be expressed as a linear combination of all of the $q$ extreme points, i.e. $X_0 = \sum_{i=1}^{q}\alpha_i \overline{X_i},$ with $\alpha_i\geq 0,$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{q}\alpha_i=1.$
Hence, the value of the objective function for $X_0$ is given as:
$f(X_0) = f(\sum_{i=1}^q\alpha_i \overline{X_i})=\alpha_1f(\overline{X_1}) + \alpha_2f(\overline{X_2}) +\cdots + \alpha_qf(X_q) = f_{max},$
where $f_{max}$ is the maximum value of $f(X).$
Let there be an extreme point $\overline{X_m}$ for which the function value is maximum.
Then, $f(X_0)\leq \sum_{i=1}^q\alpha_i f(\overline{X_i})= f(\overline{X_m})$
But, we assumed from the start that $X_0$ was the maximizing solution, which means that $f(X_0) \geq f(X), \forall X$ in the convex polyhedron, consisting of the finite set of feasible solution.
Hence, it is not possible that $f(X_0)\leq f(\overline{X_m}),$ and only possibility is $f(X_0) = f(\overline{X_m}).$
Second, it is not clear how the below two properties are derived from the above proof:

A set of $m$ linearly independent vectors from the set of $n$ vectors is associated with each extreme point.
$X$ can be an extreme point of the convex polyhedron iff the positive $x'$s are coefficients of linearly independent vectors $\overline{a_j}$ in the expression $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j\overline{a_j}=b$


The solution set of the LP $\min{ 0 | x \in \mathbb{R} }$ is $\mathbb{R}$ which has no extreme points, so there must be some additional assumptions in play.

@copper.hat Have provided the book's page link too, at the beginning. Your case is a special case; that might need an assumption of the extreme point being the same as the feasible solution set, if it comprises of a single point only.<> But, I felt that the proof must be much stronger, rather than the above. Seems a different approach is needed.

I'll just answer your first question:
Since every point of the polytope can be written as convex combination
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^q\alpha_i f(\overline{X_i})
$$
with $\alpha_i\in[0,1]$ and $\sum_{i=1}^q \alpha_i=1$, finding the maximum value of $f$ is another optimization problem, namely
$$
\max_{\alpha_i\in[0,1]} 
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^q\alpha_i f(\overline{X_i})\\
\text{wrt.}\qquad \sum_{i=1}^q \alpha_i=1
$$
Since $f$ is linear, it's easy to show that the maximum happens for $\alpha_i=1$ for some $i$ (namely whatever $i$ for which $f(\bar{X_i})$ is biggest).
So the maximum solution of a polytope is always in an extremal point.
